# Cmake - how include paths with only read access?

Tags: cmake

could you help me, please?
I'm stuck with cmake version 3.12.1.

I need to include some header files to a program that can be set up with cmake. The cmake-setting of this program originally only look for files in its own (downwards from initial CMakeLists.txt) source-directories. The header files to be included are in a read-only-path, so I'm not able to store a CMakeLists.txt in there.

Just to copy all of the read-only-path to another path is not an option, there are some hard-coded relations in it.

I modified CMakeLists via:

```
cmake \
-DCMAKE_TARGET_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES="/read/only/with/needed/headers" \
-DCMAKE_link_directories="/read/only/with/needed/headers" \
-DCMAKE ... \
```

Trying to cmake it error is:

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /home/ssd)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
CMake Warning:
  Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

    CMAKE_TARGET_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES
    CMAKE_link_directories


-- Build files have been written to: /home/ssd/.../build
```

The Code of the program is from github, but not the header I'm trying to include.
cmake just ignore my manually-specified variables, and on compiling it:

```
/home/ssd/source/somefile.cc: catastrophic error: cannot open source file "header.h"
  #include "header.h"
                                ^
```

header.h is in read only-path.

I don't know if cmake can handle this without an sub-CMakeLists.txt, but I'm quite sure I'm not the first person with this problem.
Do you have some advice?

Comment: Please show us the exact error message(s) and how you are referencing the headers in your cpp file.

Comment: Just `CCFLAGS="-I the/dir"` or same with `CMAKE_C_FLAGS`

Comment: @KamilCuk: Just to modify the compilation - its nothing depending on cmake, right? Thanks for the new approach!

Comment: So the problem is not with **read-only** property of include directories. The problem is **passing** these directories as parameters to CMake script (when invoke `cmake`). The [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12984181/specifying-include-directories-on-the-cmake-command-line) is also about this problem. Note, that would you be more detailed about your problem (Whether `header.h` belongs to some library or other project? Why your CMake project uses external header and not its own one?), the more suitable and detailed answer you could get.